# Copying VS Battles Wiki: is it feasible?

Tags: internal-consistency, internet

Imagine a world where people have superpowers. Any sort, from benign ones, like being able to spray lukewarm water, and dangerous ones- like being able to turn anything from mass to energy and vice versa. Because of this, governments around the world would have to register supers in something to the likes of threat rankings, to organize villains and heroes alike by who is stronger and weaker. Can't have the government deploying armed helicopters to stop Billy Long Tongue while Susan the Anti-Girl is rampaging on another city.

Now here's another thing- this time, you don't have to imagine it. [Battleboards](https://vsbattles.fandom.com/wiki/Tiering_System), places on the internet where people put their favorite characters against one another to see who wins. To 'objectively' rate these characters, they use tiering, power lists, and more to determine who is strongest. Those sites exist in this hypothetical world, available to the public.

So, you know what the united world did? They just copied it! No big deal! But I'm wondering: is this in any way plausible? Could a battleboard tiering system be used in real-world (by the standards of the world) scenarios?

Comment: Welcome to worldbuilding Rando, we invite you to take our [tour] and refer to our [help] as and when you have time. Enjoy the site.

Comment: If they took it then it makes enough sense for them, but will it be match for any random super system - clearly is not - "reality" has no obligations to match fantasy. Sooo why the question?

Comment: OP meant “realistic” in terms of the world

Answer (score 4):

It would do to some extent but not in an excellent way, because reality is always more complex than a ranking system. That's why people keep looking at sport events, even though a ranking system could easily prevent the players to sweat on the field for determining the final score.

According to any rating system, [Leicester City](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/2015%E2%80%9316_Leicester_City_F.C._season) in 2016 would have had 0 chances of winning the Premier League, yet it did. Same would hold for the [Brawn GP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brawn_GP) which won the F1 championship in 2009, it was so poorly evaluated that started the season with no sponsors at all.

Answer (score 2):

## The government already does this

You're describing what is called [open-source intelligence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open-source_intelligence). The intelligence community closes watches public sources of information in assessing threats. For example, imagine that the *New York Times* published a story with the headline "Exclusive: Former ISIS Fighters Joining Russian Army." You'd better believe that the CIA would read that story and compare it to their classified information on the same topic.

So yes, the government would probably keep an eye on the Battles site, but they would trust it less than information they had gathered through official channels.

Answer (score 1):

That depends on how the battleboard determines what tier the powers are. In a scenario like you described, that seems very plausible, especially if the government has had time to refine the system.